# how to deal with primitive type in reflection

Tags: java, reflection

How to call a constructor with a primitive type as argument?? the class name we will get to know at runtime.
Like we get to know the class name is Abc at runtime and we have to find all those constructor with int ,char,boolean as argument type in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`TYPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#TYPE) Class objects. Each wrapper class has one and it represents the corresponding primitive type. You can also refer to these with a class literal, e.g. `char.class`.

So if you have some class that takes a primitive in a constructor:

```
public class Abc {
    public Abc(char c) {}
}
```

You can get the constructor using the primitive type:

```
Constructor<Abc> ctor;
ctor = Abc.class.getConstructor(Character.TYPE); // Character.TYPE and
ctor = Abc.class.getConstructor(char.class);     // char.class are the same
```

Then you can invoke it with a boxed primitive:

```
Abc abc;
abc = ctor.newInstance(Character.valueOf('a')); // invoke with wrapper
abc = ctor.newInstance('a');                    // or autobox
```

You can use the primitive Class objects anywhere else you need to refer to a primitive type. Fields, Methods, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We use Wrapper class instead of primitive types in reflection